# Iterate one vector through another in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create an algorithm for a school assignment. Basically I have two vectors

`A=[1 5]` (call them 2 prices)

```
B=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10...]
```

B is a 2D matrix and continues the same pattern for many rows. I want to add a third dimension to this B array with all possible (price) combinations of A. For example

Looking at a single row for now and forgive my notation but I am trying to show all columns and then multiple dimensions behind it.

```
B(row 1)=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]

B(row 1)=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5]

B(row 1)=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 1]

B(row 1)=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 5]
```

This last section is basically counting in binary until all combinations of 1 and 5 exist as a third dimension. I'm at a loss with how to begin this project. Any ideas?

Thanks Everyone.

EDIT: To add a bit more detail. I need what Luis has suggested but in a slightly different format. My B matrix really looks like this:

```
D(:,:,1)=
 0     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     0     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     0     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     0     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     0     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     0     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     0     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     0     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     0    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
```

I then need each 3rd dimensional layer to have the same repeating pattern. Ultimately the D matrix should be <10x10x1025>

```
D(:,:,2)=
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
...
D(:,:,3)=
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5
...
D(:,:,4)=
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 1
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `B` is a vector, not a matrix.

This code generates all combinations of values of `A`, using [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) with a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b) (generated from a cell array) as output. It then contatenates along third dimension with the repeated rows of `B`.

```
B = 1:10; %// example data. Vector of arbitrary length
A = [1 5]; %// example data. Vector of arbitrary length

s = numel(B);
t = numel(A);
C = cell(1,s);
[C{:}] = ndgrid(A);
C = cat(s+1, C{:});
C = fliplr(reshape(C, t^s, s));
D = cat(3, repmat(B,t^s,1), C); %// desired result
```

---

EDIT:

If `B` is a matrix, to obtain the result of your edited question you can modify the code as follows:

```
B = [1:10; 2:11; 3:12]; %// example data. Matrix of arbitrary size
A = [1 5]; %// example data. Vector of arbitrary length

s = size(B,2);
t = numel(A);
C = cell(1,s);
[C{:}] = ndgrid(A);
C = cat(s+1, C{:});
C = fliplr(reshape(C, t^s, s));
C = repmat(permute(C, [3 2 1]), [size(B,1) 1 1]);
D = cat(3, B, C); %// desired result
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Luis. Can you possibly see my new edit above? I think you are close to getting me where I need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Well to calculate the 1's and 5's part, you could do something like this:

```
A=[1 5];
N=2^10;
C=ones(N,log2(N)+1);
for i=1:N
    d=dec2bin(i);
    for j=1:length(d)
        C(i,log2(N)+2-j)=A(str2double(d(j))+1);
    end
end
```

But I am sure there is a better way.