# Iterate one vector through another in Matlab Part 2

Tags: matlab

This is a similar request to my post at [Iterate one vector through another in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273703/iterate-one-vector-through-another-in-matlab)

I am using Luis' suggestion with the following code:

```
E=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
A = [1 2]; 
s = size(E,2);
t = numel(A);
C = cell(1,s);
[C{:}] = ndgrid(A);
C = cat(s+1, C{:});
C = fliplr(reshape(C, t^s, s));
```

This produces a good result for C as a 1024x10 matrix with all possible permutations of 1 and 2 to a length of 10 columns. What I want to do is remove any rows that are not in increasing order. For example now I get:

```
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     1
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2
```

All are valid except for the third row since it goes from 2 to back to 1.
I have code to get the desired result, but it is very slow and inefficient.

```
E=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
A = [1 2]; 
s = size(E,2);
t = numel(A);
C = cell(1,s);
[C{:}] = ndgrid(A);
C = cat(s+1, C{:});
C = fliplr(reshape(C, t^s, s));
min=0;
    for row=1:size(C,1)
        for col=1:size(C,2)
          if(C(row,col)>min)
             min=C(row,col);
          elseif(C(row,col)<min)
             C(row,:)=0; 
             continue;
          end
        end
        min=0;
    end
C = C(any(C,2),:); %remove all zero rows
```

The desired output is now:

```
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2
 1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2
 1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2
 1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2
 1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
 1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
 1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
 2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
```

Any ideas on how to optimize my code so I do not need to use nested loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The super-simple but not-quite-so-obvious solution via a couple of row-wise operations:

```
d = diff(C, [], 2);
m = min(d, [], 2);
C = C(m>=0, :);
```

Of course, in this particular example it would be *far* easier to just generate the resulting matrix directly:

```
C = flipud(triu(ones(s+1,s).*(max(A)-min(A))) + min(A));
```

but I assume you're also interested in less trivial values of `A` ;)

Comment: Thanks guys. The combination of your suggestion worked like a charm! My simulation is lightning fast in comparison.